# Square php API and applePay / Google Wallet

Tags: android-pay, square-connect, applepay

Is it possible to process payments using the square e-commerce API(php) and to prompt for ApplePay/Google wallet(/pay) on mobile devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not at this time, but we are always working on new features!